# chrome and personalized javascript file upload

Tags: javascript

I personalized the file upload and this works great in all browser, however, when i tested it in chrome, its adding "c:\fakepath\". so i read somewhere on the web to replace the path, so i did, now the problem is, the file doesn't get uploaded to my server, the path changes, but  the file fails to upload.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function BrowseClick()
{
    var fileinput = document.getElementById("picture");
    fileinput.click();
}
function changebrowse()
{
var fileinput = document.getElementById("picture");
var textinput = document.getElementById("picture2");
textinput.value = fileinput.value.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "");
}
</script>

<form method="POST" type="multipart/form-data">
<label for="test">test
<input type="text" id="picture2" readonly="true" value="myLabel"/>
<input type="button" value="myLabel" id="fakeBrowse" onclick="BrowseClick();"/>
<input name='picture' id="picture" type="file" accept="image/*" style="display: none" onChange="changebrowse();"/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

above is my code, maybe i am missing something? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need at least the method and type attributes on your form tag if you are uploading a file:

```
<form method="POST" type="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: yes I have <form method="POST" type="multipart/form-data"> in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that some browsers (like chrome) have a security feature that prevents Javascript from knowing your file's local full path, which makes sense as a client, you don't want the server to know your local machine's filesystem.

A simple solution would be to just post the entire form your fileinput is in.

Hope it helps.